# How to build and install cmake targets only if the other targets depend on them?

Tags: cmake

My application consists of the core, many shared libraries and many plugins that use these shared libraries. I'm using cmake `option()` command to enable / disable each plugin.

What I'd like to do is to build and install the shared library only if it's required by one of the enabled plugins.

I tried using the following in the directories of the shared libraries:

```
set_directory_properties(PROPERTIES EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL true)
```

However, the targets are still being built in Visual Studio. GNU make in Linux correctly avoids building them. However, the required libraries are no longer installed using `install()` in either
system.

I also tried adding `EXCLUDE_FROM_DEFAULT_BUILD false` to the library targets,
but cmake complained about the undefined behavior of `install()` with disabled targets.

Comment: When I want to selectively include subdirs, I wrap the `add_subdirectory` code in an `if` statement.  Would that be possible in your case?

Comment: No, I don't think so. How would I know if something depends on the target if the target doesn't exist yet because I haven't called `add_subdirectory`?

Comment: I see.  I was unaware you needed CMake to determine the dependencies for you... for my projects I know this ahead of time so I don't have to do it programatically.

Comment: It's difficult to know in advance, since there are many plugins and the library (or its `add_subdirectory`) should not know whether a particular plugin uses it or not.
Also, omitting `add_subdirectory` makes it impossible to build the library manually if it's disabled.

Comment: How about adding the if(target ) add_dependencies() statement in the end of your Main CMakeLists.txt? On that point, you are most likely of knowing which targets exist.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have something like this:

```
OPTION( BUILD_OPTIONAL_PLUGINS "Build plugins that are not required for core install" FALSE) 
IF(${BUILD_OPTIONAL_PLUGINS}) 
    ADD_SUBDIRECTORY( Plugins/Optional) # Whatever it really is. 
ENDIF()
```

So far so good. However, you now can have a library like "libCommon" that nobody needs if all those option flags are false.

So, your simplest solution is this: Treat the library as optional TOO!

After all, you don't need to even build it if none of the consuming projects themselves are going to be built. So have an ordinary 'SET' variable like 'BUILD_COMMON' in that same top-level CMakeLists.txt, defaulted to TRUE. Then just do this:

```
SET( BUILD_COMMON 0) 
IF(${BUILD_OPTIONAL_1} OR ...) # Detect if you need to build the lib 
    SET( BUILD_COMMON 1) 
ENDIF()

IF(${BUILD_COMMON}) 
   ADD_SUBDIRECTORY( common)
ENDIF()
```

Then when you eventually do 'make install' on this build, everything works as expected. If turned off all the optional plugins, the library that was only being used by them never got built either. Since it was never in the build, you don't need to try and make its install logic aware of whether it is needed or not.

You should also add a line like this to the INSTALL() command for the library as well as every optional plugin:

```
INSTALL( TARGETS <plugin> .... OPTIONAL)
```

That tells 'make install' to not try and build or install the target if it doesn't see its binaries.